# get file path from local drive with jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem at the moment when I want to get the file path. This is my code:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String cabArch = req.getParameter("fRutaArch");
    String rutaArch = getFileName(filePart);
}
```

And in jsp I have this:

```
<td align="left" class="e2">
  <input type="file" name="fRutaArch" id="fRutaArch" title="Seleccionar archivo">                       
</td>
<td>
  <button type="submit" name="bCargar" id="bCargar">Cargar</button>
</td>
```

I just need the full file path, please any advice?

Comment: I think you actually don't want the path of the file on client side (usually that's impossible), but Upload a file to a servlet. As such you may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/) interesting

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a impossible solution xD anyways thanks I'll try to use another way for my porpuse

Answer (score 0):

You can add `a hidden field` in the html code and  modify the `service` function

the code follows below

```
<td align="left" class="e2">
<input type="file" name="fRutaArch" id="fRutaArch" title="Seleccionar   archivo" onchange="document.getElementById('filepath').value=this.value" >                       
</td>
<td>
<button type="submit" name="bCargar" id="bCargar">Cargar</button>
</td>
<input type='hidden' name='filepath' id='filepath'/>
```

then the function `service`

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
String cabArch = req.getParameter("filepath");
String rutaArch = getFileName(cabArch);
```

}